# Use babylon glossary in an open source (GPL) dictionary app

Tags: gpl, copyright, open-data

I want use babylon glossary in an open source (GPL) dictionary app.
They don't have any license in them. Can I use them?

What about glossaries of commercial dictionaries like oxford, longman, …? Ccan I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what the app is, exactly, nor how it uses the glossary.  I'm assuming that the glossary is used as a words list, which is then served up by the app.

If that is the case, then the app's GPL status has no effect on your ability to use the glossary.  If this glossary is transmitted to you under terms that allow you so to use it, then you can; if it doesn't, you can't.

In the case of the three glossaries you ask about (babylon, oxford, longman), the first has no licence attached.  Copyright law's default position is clear; assuming that a work is eligible for copyright protection at all, it acquires such protection by the act of its creation, so you can do *next to nothing* with it without violating that copyright.  You certainly can't make a copy of it, for use with your app or otherwise.  The other two are known to be commercial glossaries, and it is unlikely that they will be supplied to you under licence terms that permit their reuse in that way (that could be wrong, but you won't know until you read each licence).

**tl; dr**: it depends on the licences on the glossaries, and on very little else.